# Socle of a quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra, socle

I want to know the form of the left socle of a factor ring $R/I$, where $I$ is an ideal of a unital ring $R$. It is, by definition, the sum of all simple left ideals of the ring $R/I$. So, one should realize, first, the form of a simple left ideal of $R/I$. I do know that any left ideal of this factor ring is of the form $X/I$, where $X$ is any left ideal of $R$ containing $I$. If this is simple, one infer that no left ideal of $R$ sits between $I$ and $X$. Is there a concise representation of the left socle of $R/I$ via the above expressions? or, is there any relation between the left socles of $R$ and $R/I$?

Thanks for any cooperation!

Comment: Say that the left ideal $B$ is a *cover* of the left ideal $A$ if $B/A$ is simple. Then the left socle of $R/I$ is $C/I$ where $C$ is the sum of all covers of $I$. I don’t think you can say much more than this, in general. Think to the integers modulo $n$ for realizing that you can’t establish general relationships.

Comment: The socle is connected to the bottom of a ring, not the top. It will be related to docked of sub modules, not quotients. The dual object, the Jacobson radical, is the opposite.

Comment: Sorry, autocorrect turned one of my “socles” into “docked”.